# Word guessing game – how to print blanks

Tags: python

I am having trouble with making a guessing game. When you guess a correct letter it prints out the letter but not the blanks (_).

Comment: What part(s) of your code attempt to do these things?

Comment: I was trying to get this line "newBlanks = secret[location]" to do it! But the entire while loop is supposed to be the game. newBlanks is supposed to bring the blanks with the correct guessed letters.

Comment: Since `location` is where you found `guess`, then what do you think is `secret[location]`? How does that relate to the output you want?

Comment: I thought that line would indicate where the correctly guessed letter would go. My professor recommended that letter to me. I am 3 weeks into this python course and very confused on this lab.

Comment: How would you deal with words that have a letter more than once, like "letter"?

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly is right, the current code can't handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `newBlanks = secret[location]` doesn't work because it does not save the new guess in the list `blanks`. You can try editing the list instead of making a new variable on it.

```
print("Hello user! Would you like to guess what word I am thinking of? You may guess one letter at a time!")
print("You also only have 10 guesses!")

secret = "monkey"
count = 10
blanks = ["_"]*len(secret)
print(*blanks)

while count > 0: 
    guess = input("What letter would you like to guess? ")

    # check if the letter is in the word
    if guess in secret:
        location = secret.find(guess)
        blanks[location] = guess  # Edit the list
        print(f"(guessed {guess}) --> ",*blanks)  # print updated list
        count = count - 1

    # if NOT, tell the player it isn't in the word
    else:
        print ("that letter is not in the word")
        count = count - 1
```

Comment: how would I edit a list to place the correctly guessed letter in the spot that the letter goes in the word. I am new at python. I know how to edit a list by writing a new edit, but i dont know how to write code where the computer finds the spot in the list where the letter would go. (if that makes sense?). My professor recommended that line of code to me. I wanted to have the letter be placed and then "+ blanks"

Comment: You can index the location in the list, as in `blanks[location] = guess`.

Comment: You can try 'good', then it won't work. I suppose you need to update something to handle the repeated letter.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this can help you.

```
#Question 3 - Strings
#get guess from user
print("Hello user! Would you like to guess what word I am thinking of? You may guess one letter at a time!")
print("You also only have 10 guesses!")
secret = "good"
secret = list(secret)
newBlanks = ["_"]*len(secret)
print(*newBlanks)
count = 10

while count > 0:
    guess = input("What letter would you like to guess?")
    #check if the letter is in the word
    if guess in secret:
        location = secret.index(guess)
        secret[location] = '_'
        newBlanks[location] = guess
        print(newBlanks)
        # print(set(secret))
        count = count - 1
    #if NOT tell the player it isn't in the word
    else:
        print("that letter is not in the word")
        count = count - 1
    if set(secret) == {'_'}:
        print("You have successfully guessed all the letters!")
        break
```

Comment: what does" # pdb.set_trace()" mean?

Comment: Oh, just ignore it. It's some debug code, I have commented it out.

Answer (score 0):

You did not update `blanks` when a correct guess is made. This is why your guess isn't being saved/displayed.

Code:

```
#Question 3 - Strings 
#get guess from user
print("Hello user! Would you like to guess what word I am thinking of? You may guess one letter at a time!")
print("You also only have 10 guesses!")
secret = "monkey"
blanks = ["_"]*len(secret)
print(*blanks)
count = 10 

while count > 0: 
    # if user guessed all letters, they win!
    if "".join(blanks) == secret:
        print("You win!")
        break
    guess = input("What letter would you like to guess?")
    #check if the letter is in the word
    if guess in secret:
        location = secret.find(guess)
        # store correct guess
        blanks[location] = guess
        # output new blanks -> sample: _ o _ _ _ _
        print(" ".join(blanks))
        count = count - 1
    #if NOT tell the player it isn't in the word
    else:
        print ("that letter is not in the word")
        count = count - 1
```

I also added a message to be printed when the user guesses the whole word.

Happy coding!

Comment: As an above user stated, this code doesn't cover the case where the secret word has duplicate letters. That's something to consider if the assignment requires it later on.